# C++ default initialization

Tags: c++

According to C++ Primer (4th Edition) by Stanley Lipmann, on page 50 it says:

> "Variables defined outside any function body are initialized to 0."

Based on what I read it seems it is not true.

A global `char` is default to blank and not 0.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: `'0'` does not have the character code 0. The character code 0 is null (at least in ASCII, not sure if anything strays from that).

Comment: What do you mean `A global char is default to blank`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When he prints out an uninitialized `char` variable it comes out blank.

Comment: AFAIK 0 is required to be nul terminator.

Comment: @David: I am asking the OP to clarify his language.

Comment: There's no such thing as "blank" in C++.

Comment: Sori for all the confusions.Thanks guys. Appreciate all your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
char global;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Value of Global " << ((int)global) << "\n";
}
```

`global` here is a static storage duration object and as such will be zero initialized.
I cast it (very lazily) to an integer so that the stream will print out its value (rather than the character) just to show that it is zero.

Printing out the char '\0' is not going to print anything useful.

Comment: Printing out the char `'\-'` is undefined behavior, unless the stream was opened in binary mode (which isn't the case for `std::cout`).

Answer (score 9):

Stanley is correct — *objects with static storage duration are zero-initialised before any other initialisation takes place*.

So, in your terminology, a global `char` *is* "defaulted" to `0`. This is the integer `0`, and *not* the character `'0'` (which is usually `48`). When you try to stream it to a console, you won't see anything, as this `char` value has no human-readable representation.

If you meant a global `char*` or `char const*`, then this is also "defaulted" to `0`, i.e. it will be a null pointer. This is *not* the same as a pointer to an empty string. Trying to stream this will result in undefined behaviour, so you could see nothing or you could see my Mum's recipe for tomato soup presented in the form of interpretive dance at 20Hz behind an ASCII art translation layer.

Neither will be "blank", though without knowing what "blank" means here I cannot say that with absolute certainty.

Answer (score 3):

`'0'` is not `0`. When it states *initialized to 0* it means the value `0` (which is also `\0` or `NULL`), not the character `'0'` (which is 48 in ASCII encoding).